# Картинка на фоне переворачивается

Tags: html, css

Картинка показывается нормально, если ее вставить с помощью img, но если ее присвоить диву как фон - она переворачивается на 90 градусов. Помогите, уже голову сломал.

**Обновление**

Вместо `$(this).attr('href')` подставляется путь к картинке.
Код тут: http://pastebin.com/LAQTVERD

Comment: Покажите код.

Comment: Чтобы идентифицировать проблему слишком мало входных данных, из того, что есть, на 90 градусов картинка точно не повернётся, попробуйте в отладчике firefox или chrome посмотреть, какие ещё стили применяются к диву, либо сделайте (думаю, вряд ли получится, но мало ли) рабочий пример на  http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в EXIF-данных изображения. То есть картинка была сделана изначально в одном положении фотоаппарата, а потом повернута на 90 градусов в редакторе типа ACDSee или IrfanView. Попробуйте открыть ее в фотошопе, перевернуть на 90 градусов, сохранить, потом вернуть обратно и пересохранить.